# creating a two-dimensional array filled with an enum in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array, enums

I want to create a two-dimensional array filled with an enum in TypeScript and I did a lot of research but found nothing I could use.
This is the code I now have written so far:

```
enum States { neutral, one, two };

export let gameField: States[][];
gameField = [];

for(var i: number = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   gameField = [];
   for(var j: number = 0; j< 10; j++) {
      gameField[j] = States.neutral;
   }
 }
```

But the line `gameField[j] = States.neutral;` produces following error-message:
"The Type "States.neutral" can not be assigned to the type "States[]""

So my question now is: What is wrong at this piece of code and how can I fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that you are trying to assign a single value of type `States` to a type of `States[]` (array of `States`). In your code you aren't actually creating a 2D array, but a one-dimensional one.

Here I fixed it for you:

```
enum States {
  neutral,
  one,
  two
}

export let gameField: States[][];
gameField = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  gameField[i] = Array(10);
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    gameField[i][j] = States.neutral;
  }
}
```

A tip: you don't need to declare the type of variables which are assigned, e.g. `var a: number = 1`, since the TypeScript compiler can infer them automatically.